# RedirectToAction fails on production server due to path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Working on MVC5 app. In my c# code I'm running a RedirectToAction....

```
return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "WidgetResults", 
        new { id = eventId, chartNumber = 1 });
```

Locally this works perfect. My local URL this code runs from is:

```
http://localhost:59328/WidgetResults/Index/35
```

And redirects to....

```
http://localhost:59328/WidgetResults/Index/35?chartNumber=1
```

But, when I run it on my production server the RedirectToAction resulting URL fails with the error...

```
404 File or Directory not found
```

That's because the production URL has an extra subdirectory in it, "/Widget"....

```
http://Widget.Company.com/Widget/WidgetResults/DeleteChartData?eventId=222&chartNumber=2
```

But, the redirect IMPROPERLY goes to... (without the extra "/Widget" in the URL)

```
http://Widget.Company.com/WidgetResults/DeleteChartData?eventId=222&chartNumber=2
```

How can I adjust the redirect so it takes into account whatever the true "root" of the website currently is?

Comment: Check out this article on SO. Might be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968979/mvc-routing-does-not-work-for-non-default-root-action-controller-on-virtual-dire

Comment: @GlennFerrie thanks but it doesn't. I believe my issue is more at the code level than the server level?

Comment: is the /widget/ folder set up as an application or a virtual folder? cause if it is a virtual folder the application root is `/` not `/widget`

Comment: @MichaelCoxon In IIS, it's set up as a web app under "Default Website". The alias is "/widget" (alias was required.) I'd really wish it wasn't required though. That's why my production URL has to be http://Widget.Company.com/Widget/ as the root. Suggestions welcomed! (Not having the /Widget alias would fix the problem.)

Comment: that still does not answer what I asked. In IIS you can set a folder as a virtual directory OR an application. To run MVC it must be an application.When you say 'alias' it sounds like you made a virtual folder - not an application

Comment: To add to it - it means you can have an app pool for a folder

Comment: @MichaelCoxon thanks. It's an MVC site, so it's setup as an application. The "alias" I referred to is under the "basic settings" area. Hopes this answers your question. And, there is an app pool defined. Sorry.

Comment: Any ideas on this?